# Xcode: sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: iPad issue with system text color?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, fonts, storyboard

I am using `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` to work out the required height of  my UITableViewcell's. The below code works fine in iPhone and iPad.

In IB (Storyboard) I have set the text color to "Dark Gray Color" (I am using separate storyboards for iPhone and iPad and I have set the colour in both.). iPhone behaves perfectly. iPad however is not using my Dark Gray, instead it apparently uses the default text color (Black) and I can't seem to change it. Is this perhaps a known bug or have I done something wrong?

Is there perhaps a way to add the text color programmatically in my `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` or somewhere else?

Much appreciated.

```
if ([self.storyDescription description]) summary = [self.storyDescription description];

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            CGSize s = [summary sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] 
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, MAXFLOAT)  // - 40 For cell padding
                           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            return s.height + 20; // Add padding
        } else {
            CGSize s = [summary sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18] 
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, MAXFLOAT)  // - 40 For cell padding
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            return s.height + 40; // Add padding
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` simply calculates the size of an `NSString`. Since `NSString` has no notion of colors, this method doesn't care about color either.

You should set the color in the Xcode Storyboard editor in the `UILabel` inspector. Alternatively, you can set a `UITableViewCell`'s `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` in the `UITableView` data source/delegate methods.

Comment: I did set the color in Xcode Storyboard but again, it only works for iPhone. IPad doesn't seem to care no matter what I set in storyboard. I ended up doing it programmatically:                     `if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
        cell.textLabel.textColor =  [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor lightTextColor];
        cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);  
    } `